# Access Datasheet view appears to be blank(charaters appear in white hence not visible) in WSS3.0

Tags: ms-access, wss

Access Datasheet view  appears to be blank(charaters appear in white hence not visible) in WSS3.0

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a styling problem on your SharePoint page.

Comment: How can the styling be changed on the sharepoint page so that my datasheet is visible

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue fixed, only the page property needed to be changed and it worked. Now the data sheet is visible with data inside it in balck color